# pgbouncer config File descriptor limit, max_client_conn, max fds possible

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I had a PostgreSQL based web application that run into no connection left problem. so I used pgbouncer to solve this problem. It works very much better with pgbouncer but I'm still having some problems with connection limit...
Right now my postgresql.conf file contains:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128MB
#temp_buffers = 8MB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0
#work_mem = 1MB
#maintenance_work_mem = 16MB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB
#temp_file_limit = -1
#max_files_per_process = 1000
#shared_preload_libraries = ''
```

and my pgbouncer.ini file:

```
pool_mode = session
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 45
reserve_pool_size = 1
```

It still encounters some connection limit problems at peak time of site.
Can you help me configure this settings to better configuration.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want your pgbouncer conf to match that of the PostgreSQL limits? I'd personally increase max_connections to something 20% higher than pgbouncer. Secondly, what resource is allocated to the machine in terms of RAM? Is there any reason you only have the default max_connection set to 100 when PostgreSQL is capable of dealing with at least 5+ times this? 

Understanding the underlying infrastructure will help. Can you also post your work_mem setting?

Comment: work_mem is commented but default value is 1MB